# why will the program not print 10 number. the error cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class number {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        for( int i=1;i<=10;i++);
        {
            System.out.print( i);
        }
    }
```

the compilation error that keeps occurring is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field i
```

Comment: assistance required

Comment: I think Reimeus didn't read the question carefully enough, although the compile error that you're posting is completely unrelated to the actual problem

Comment: You wouldn't actually get that error for this code: you'd need a non-static field `i` for that to occur.

Answer (score 1):

you have an additional semicolon in your for loop:

```
import java.io.*;

class number {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for( int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.print( i);
        }
    }
}
```